# Программная активация табличной части в 1с

Tags: 1с

у меня такая задача: есть чекбокс на форме справочника и 2 табличные части, одна из которых изначально скрыта. При активации чекбокса должна стать видимой табличная часть и стать активной.[image: форма, когда чекбокс не активен] [image: форма, когда чекбокс активен] [image: что должно быть при активации чекбокса]

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПриОткрытии(Отказ)
    Элементы.Дети.Видимость = Ложь;
    
КонецПроцедуры
//Код скрытия табличной части вначале

&НаКлиенте
Процедура НаличиниеДетейПриИзменении(Элемент)
    Если Объект.НаличиниеДетей = Истина Тогда
        Элементы.Дети.Видимость = Истина;
            Иначе
        Элементы.Дети.Видимость = Ложь;
    КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры
//Код включения видимости табличной части
```

Comment: 1 картинка - до активации чекбокса
2 картинка - после активации чекбокса
3 картинка - что должно быть при активации чекбокса

Comment: А вопрос в чём?!

Comment: как сделать так, чтобы было вместо того, что на 2 картинке, было то, что на 3 картинке

Answer (score 1):

на основе ответа santavital, сделал так:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура НаличиниеДетейПриИзменении(Элемент)
    Если Объект.НаличиниеДетей = Истина Тогда
        Элементы.Дети.Видимость = Истина;
        ЭтаФорма.ТекущийЭлемент = ЭтаФорма.Элементы.СведенияОДетях;
    Иначе
        Элементы.Дети.Видимость = Ложь;
    КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры
//Добавил строку ЭтаФорма.ТекущийЭлемент = ЭтаФорма.Элементы.СведенияОДетях;
//которая активирует элемент СведенияОДетях
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ЭтаФорма.Элементы.Вкладки.ТекущаяСтраница = ЭтаФорма.Элементы.СведенияОДетях;
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо, попробовал ваш вариант, 1с ругается на "Вкладки"

Поле объекта не обнаружено (Вкладки)
{Справочник.ФизическиеЛица.Форма.ФормаЭлемента.Форма(38)}:  ЭтаФорма.Элементы.Вкладки.ТекущаяСтраница = ЭтаФорма.Элементы.СведенияОДетях;

Comment: Спасибо вам большое